# Computing gradient of Reduced Order Model (ROM) basis w.r.t time?

Tags: reduced-order-modeling

For surrogate modeling Reduced Order Models seem relatively common. And in particular one approach is called P.O.D. (proper orthogonal decomposition). Which essentially computes a linear manifold of the original state variables.

How do these reduced order models save compute costs? In particular once you have the reduced manifold: $\forall t, r_t \in R^m, f_t \in R^n, W \in R^{m,n}$ s.t. $m<n$ where $_t=*f_t$, you could compute the gradient of the reduced basis w.r.t. time naively by $\dot r_t=W*\dot f_t$. But this requires relying on the original state space, how is this avoided in practice?

P.S. $f_t:=$ FOM state at time t, $r_t:=$ ROM state at time t

**Important:** the accepted answer uses different notation (in particular they have $W\leftarrow W^T$ and $a(t)=r_t$), see that answer’s comments for reconciliation with my notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, consider a linear evolution equation $\dot{u} = Au$ and an orthonormal reduced basis $W$. We make the ansatz $u_r(t)\approx Wa(t)$, where $a$ are the modal coefficients in the reduced subspace. We then substitute into the original equation to obtain $$W\dot{a} = AWa.$$ I believe this is about what your equation says, and it takes values in the full state space. However, we can reduce the dimension by projecting this equation onto the subspace spanned by the columns of $W$. This has the effect of minimizing the residual between the true and reduced states in state space. In this case, the projection is obtained by just multiplying on the left by $W^T$. Using the fact that $W^TW = I$, we obtain $$\dot{a} = W^TAWa,$$ which is now takes values in the reduced coordinates. Furthermore, we can compute $W^TAW$ *a priori*, so that no full-order intermediate calculations are needed in the simulation of the reduced-order system.

Comment: I'm a little confused because I thought that W would be applied to u to reduce the state space? Or in your notation: $u_r(t) \approx Wu(t)$

Comment: $u_r$ represents the state in the reduced basis as a linear combination of columns of $W$. $a$ is the vector of coefficients in the reduced space that are actually evolved by the ROM.

Comment: What coefficients? In the problem I'm working on we just have 2 state spaces, the FOM state space: $u(t)$, and the ROM state space: $u_r(t)$. Also we get the reduced state space from: $u_r(t)=Wu(t)$. I apologize if this is a naive question...

Comment: I think we are using slightly different language to describe the same things. In my answer, I refer to the full-order state $u$, as well as the reduced state $u_r = Wa$. $u$ and $u_r$ lie in the same full-order space, but $u_r$ is an element of the linear subspace spanned by the columns of $W$. $W$ is a $N_{FOM}\times N_{ROM}$ matrix and $a$ are the coefficients that specify $u_r$ in the $W$ basis. I believe in your characterization, you are using $u_r$ in place of $a$ if I understand correctly.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is you create a linear manifold (the ROM state space) from a. Whereas in my problem we are creating it from u. I presume in your setup $a(t)\neq u$, otherwise you'd use one variable...

Comment: Or to use the terminology from my question: I have $r_t=Wf_t$ s.t. $f_t$:=  FOM state at time t, $r_t$:= ROM state at time t. But you are somehow deriving the ROM state from something other than the FOM state? (so to clarify I'm not using $u_r$ in the place of $a$, I'm actually expecting $u$ where I'm seeing $a(t)$ in your eqs.).

Comment: $a$ are coordinates in the ROM state space. $W$ transforms them back up to the FOM state space. I think your $W$ and my $W$ are transposes of each other or something similar.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case your answer makes sense! Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! This is one of those topics where everyone has a different notation that makes sense to them and it's sometimes hard to translate

Answer (score 2):

1. How does ROM save compute costs?

For linear PDEs, the computational savings are easy to see. Just imagine that for the full order problem (the original high fidelity problem) you need to solve the linear system
$$
A^{FOM}x^{FOM} = b^{FOM}.
$$
Note that this linear system scales with the number of degrees of freedom and we can easily have $x^{FOM} \in \mathbb{R}^{10^5}$ (or even more DoFs). (I did not include any dependency of the linear system on parameters $\mu$ or time $t$ but that can also be added.)
On the other hand, when solving the reduced order model, for most cases one only has on the order of 10 to 100 POD vectors, i.e. the linear system
$$
A^{ROM}x^{ROM} = b^{ROM}
$$
is much smaller and thus takes very little time to solve for $x^{ROM}$.
For linear problems, we can also precompute/assemble the reduced linear system in the offline stage, e.g. following your notation $A^{ROM} = W^T A^{FOM} W$. Now what people do is that they compare how long it takes to solve $x^{ROM}$ compared to solving for $x^{FOM}$. ROM becomes especially interesting when you have parametric problems, e.g. there is some uncertainty of the material paremters, you want to try out different parametrized domains, ... For these multi-query applications ROM is great. Although I purposely ignored nonlinear PDEs, you can also use ROM there by employing hyperreduction methods for the nonlinear terms.

2. Computing the derivatives of the reduced basis

I do not understand why you want to compute derivatives of the reduced basis. If you have derivatives in your PDE, then you already assembly e.g. the Laplace matrix with the FOM and then reduce it to the FOM as explained in 1) (see also https://github.com/mathmerizing/POD-ROM). Nevertheless, if you explicitly need to compute derivaties of your ROM solution, I would precompute the derivatives of the FOM basis and then by linearity of the POD ansatz the derivative of the ROM solution is again just a linear combination of the derivative of the FOM basis.

Comment: @Julian_Roth I'm kind of assuming that there aren't computational savings if you *still* need to compute derivatives of all the original state variables. Because I don't see where the computational savings happen then.

But I also don't entirely understand the context of you solving a linear system in the beginning. Is that always needed in order to compute state derivates?

Comment: Derivatives of the basis with respect to what? As Julian mentions, if you need to take e.g., spatial derivatives of the basis to project the system onto the subspace, that only needs to be done once in most cases. Generally, you only ever have to move back up to the full state space during the ROM simulation if you have some nonpolynomial nonlinearities

Comment: @whpowell96 & Julian_Roth: Sorry I meant derivatives/gradient of the reduced basis state w.r.t. to time. Please see my updated/clarified question.

Comment: @profPlum Could you please explain why you want to compute the time derivative and what you use it for?

Comment: @profPlum You usually do not do anything relying on the original state space / the FOM when you actually use your reduced order model. The workflow is as follows:
1) [OFFLINE] Compute many FOM snapshots.
2) [OFFLINE] Compute reduced basis from FOM snapshots.
3) [OFFLINE] Assemble reduced system/PDE from reduced basis and full order system.
4) [ONLINE] Solve reduced system which is only of dimension $m \ll n$. From this you get the solution $r_t$ and by post processing with e.g finite differences you could also get $\partial_t r_t$.

Comment: @JulianRoth Without the time derivative how are you going to move the simulation forward in time? Without a simulation moving in time it isn't really a simulation at all.

Comment: @JulianRoth that being said I think your comment answers my question. You should update your answer.

Comment: @profPlum There are also time-independent problems that only depend on material paremters, see https://docs.pymor.org/latest/tutorial_projection.html. Therefore, I kept my answer very general. But whpowell96 had a great compact summary of POD for time-dependent problems and for more in depth explanations, you can look at my POD tutorial on GitHub:  https://github.com/mathmerizing/POD-ROM